# A word for a labeled behavioral pattern

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe a labeled behavioral pattern that we might observe in someone.

For example: A person whose focus is primarily on getting promoted, might be labeled a "corporate climber".

Clearly, this isn't a job title. I don't think "role" fits either, and "label" seems too vague. Other words I've considered but am not totally happy with: "stereotype", "personality type", "trait". It's hard to describe why I'm not happy with them though. I'm just hoping someone will suggest something else.

---

UPDATE: I'm thinking maybe "persona". I think "characteristic" answers my question, but it's not quite what I'm looking for, so probably the description in my question isn't right. Arrgh. Verbalizing things is so hard!

Comment: A *characteristic*?

Comment: Do you want a word for the label or a word for the behavior? Are you using the word **labeled** to mean "recognized/identified"?

Comment: "Corporate climber" is a label for a person who exhibits a certain set of behaviors. "Father", "Manager" are other labels. An individual could be all of these at once. The latter two are *roles*, but "corporate climber" isn't really a role. And "Father" isn't really a characteristic. Ideally I'd like a word that encompasses all of these (other than "label").

Comment: Your concept is not very clearly delineated. Would "Yuppie" be an analogous label? Or do you mean to steer clear of demographic groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps *[archetype](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/archetype)*

> A very typical example of a certain person or thing:
>   *the book is a perfect archetype of the genre*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest '**[Characteristic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/characteristic)**', being *a typical or noticeable quality of someone or something*.

Comment: Thanks. I've upvoted this because it's probably the closest answer to my question, but "archetype" is closer to what I actually wanted!

Answer (score 1):

"social climber" could be called an **epithet**.

Answer (score 0):

Try [essence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essence) - the basic nature of a thing : the quality or qualities that make a thing what it is. **The properties or attributes by means of which something can be placed in its proper class or identified as being what it is. **

Also [nature](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nature)- the way that a person behaves: the character or personality of a person. It also means the inherent character or basic constitution of a person or thing.